# Zero product of three matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ be singular matrices such that the matrix products $AB$ and $BC$ are not zero. Does this imply that the product $ABC$ is also not zero?

**Update:** in general, to show that the matrix product $ABC$ is not zero would it be sufficient to show that the image of $C$ is not in the kernel of $B$ and that the image of $B$ is not in the kernel of $A$? I.e. to show that $\mathrm{Ker}(B) \cap\mathrm{Im}(C) = \emptyset$ and $\mathrm{Ker}(A) \cap\mathrm{Im}(B) = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.  As a counterexample, consider
$$
A = B = C = \pmatrix{0&1&0\\0&0&1\\0&0&0}
$$

Comment: I suspect that your condition holds, however, if we require that $A,B,C$ have size $2 \times 2$

Comment: As a follow-up question: given a finite set of matrices (e.g. three A,B,C), what would be the condition that guarantees that no product of any number of those matrices can be zero? Valid products would for example be ABAAC or CCB or ABC or AAACBBBA etc.

Comment: There are certainly conditions that guarantee this outcome (e.g. if $A,B,C$ are non-singular or if $A,B,C$ commute with some additional conditions), but I don't know of any nice necessary conditions for this outcome.